# symfony 2 Doctrine leftJoin NOT IN

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

How can I solve a query where I want to get all data from the left table which isn't existing in the right table?

left table: ID | NAME | DATE
right table: ID | ID_left_table | NAME | DATE

It is confusing me a bit since I haven't got that experience with doctrine.

My entitys look like:

```
class NameData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name",  type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;
.
.
.
```

and

```
class ValueData
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestBundle\Entity\NameData")
     */
    private $nameid;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name",  type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
         */
        private $date;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: You have to include your entity definitions if you ask a question like that, if you didn't know that you should have studied a bit of doctrine before asking this question.

Comment: I edited my question and add my entity-classes. Do I need to add a "joinColumn"  into my ManytoOne ?

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, fix $nameid property annotation in ValueData entity to this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameData")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="name_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $nameData;
```

This is basic Doctrine annotation mapping for relationships, in this case **ManyToOne**.

2) Modify valueData table to add foreign key, by typing **php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force** or with [migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

3) let Symfony generate the right setters and getters for ValueData entity, by running command in your console **php app/console doctrine:generate:entities TestBundle:ValueData**.

4) And then, if you need to get data in controller:

```
$valueData = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:ValueData')->find(1);//Find by ID 1 OR ->findAll() to get all records
$nameData = $valueData->getNameData(); //This line of code behind the scenes will 
//join the valueData table with nameData, and get associated data
```

Add a comment if you will need help along the way.

**Edit:**

Below is the query builder to select all NameDatas which dont have any ValueData:

```
$nameDataRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:NameData');
$nameDatasWithoutDatavalues = $nameDataRepo->createQueryBuilder('nameData')
    ->leftJoin('nameData.dataValues', 'dataValue')
    ->where('dataValue.id IS NULL')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult
```

Also, make sure to write bi-directional part of doctrine relationships, to be able to access children from parent entity NameData.php:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ValueData", mappedBy="nameData")
 */
 private $valueDatas;

 /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->valueDatas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And in ValueData.php, edit $nameData property annotation to this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameData", inversedBy="valueDatas")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="name_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
 private $nameData;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. this is how I get  normal output from doctrine. 

But in my case, I only store data inside the ValueData table, when there is a need for. If this happens, I have to take care that this data won't be selected a second time.

Therefor, I need to select all data from NameData which is not stored in ValueData.  

Thats why I need a join which checks all Data from NameData which doesn't exist in ValueData. For the reason that a "NOT IN" might be probably slower than a join, I decided to use a join. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to select NameData record with all it's ^childs^ (ValueData records related to that NameData)?

Comment: Hehe, no . sorry for the confusion. I want to select all NameData which has no entry (by ID) in the ValueData Table. Something like SELECT * FROM NameData LEFT JOIN (ValueData) ON (NameData.Id != ValueData.nameid). But I don't know how to set this the right way in querybuilder

Comment: Yeah it's a bit confusing, but I think now I understand. I updated code, tell me if this will work as you want.